# Cant get API Gateway `RequestId` in Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I sent a post and get the response from amazon API Gateway as:

```
{"MD5OfMessageBody": "bc709a65868c21309969a07cfeeac12f", "MD5OfMessageAttributes": "8a66ae91e9109cb75717520c287736eb", "MessageId": "b70a5453-5f30-4914-8006-b6cf7fa4ff93", "ResponseMetadata": {"RequestId": "1a38fbb5-859a-53f9-9551-a805d864768c", "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": {"server": "Server", "date": "Fri, 29 Jun 2018 16:18:06 GMT", "content-type": "text/xml", "content-length": "459", "connection": "keep-alive", "x-amzn-requestid": "1a38fbb5-859a-53f9-9551-a805d864768c"}, "RetryAttempts": 0}}
```

When I look in the event object passed into the handler function in lambda:
`def lambda_handler(event, context):`

```
{'resource': '/python_job_to_sqs', 'path': '/python_job_to_sqs', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto': 'https', 'CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer': 'true', 'CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Viewer-Country': 'US', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': '5p1xcqn2y5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.14.2', 'Via': '1.1 c7db0c4b178dd73a64add79be10805c2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'QkdNKg7VrrB6tJ0wynZwYvCxSYpLMTGkm9CK6CsYhw-jLDqTI0-x6g==', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-5b365bbd-9dd143fc6325d468485f44a0', 'X-Forwarded-For': '38.77.16.218, 204.246.180.73', 'X-Forwarded-Port': '443', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https'}, 'queryStringParameters': None, 'pathParameters': None, 'stageVariables': None, 'requestContext': {'resourceId': 'i42qmv', 'resourcePath': '/python_job_to_sqs', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'extendedRequestId': 'JQNFqFZjoAMFf8g=', 'requestTime': '29/Jun/2018:16:18:05 +0000', 'path': '/production/python_job_to_sqs', 'accountId': '130491730454', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 'stage': 'production', 'requestTimeEpoch': 1530289085866, 'requestId': '012c013f-7bb8-11e8-bed9-1ff9514513cd', 'identity': {'cognitoIdentityPoolId': None, 'accountId': None, 'cognitoIdentityId': None, 'caller': None, 'sourceIp': '38.77.16.218', 'accessKey': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationType': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationProvider': None, 'userArn': None, 'userAgent': 'python-requests/2.14.2', 'user': None}, 'apiId': '5p1xcqn2y5'}, 'body': '{"input": [{"value": "test.co", "fieldName": "tld"}]}, 'isBase64Encoded': False}
```

It seems in other frameworks the `requestContext['requestId']` which here is `012c013f-7bb8-11e8-bed9-1ff9514513cd` is supposed to be the request ID passed in from the API Gateway. But `012c013f-7bb8-11e8-bed9-1ff9514513cd != 1a38fbb5-859a-53f9-9551-a805d864768c`. Is this a bug in their framework that they're replacing this with the lambda function ID?

Comment: You already appear to have an open [question very similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51091418/1695906).  Please delete one of them.

Comment: Thanks I did, do you have any insight into this?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get requestId of API Gateway by using 'event'.

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
   request = event["requestContext"]
   request_id = request["requestId"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are looking for the context["aws_request_id"] this is the [identifier of the invocation request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html) and can be used to query CloudWatch logs with filter @requestId = "{your request id}".
Try:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(f"request_id:  {context.aws_request_id}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use mapping template to pass requestId to lambda function

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference

Comment: requestId is the ID of the lambda function. That request ID is never given to the user sending a POST to the API gateway. I need to get the `"MessageId"`, that is given to the user, also sent to the lambda function. There is no `messageId` under the mapping template

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Mapping templates can't be defined for proxy lambdas, but even if they were it would contain the same requestId as what's in the context object passed to the method handler. Which, as the OP describes, doesn't match the id returned in the CloudFront response, and is thus not helpful as a correlation id.